# Installing Eclipse PDE Plugin in Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am having difficulty getting my Eclipse PDE plugin to work in a Windows environment. I have created an Eclipse PDE plugin that uses external jars. I was able to install the plugin to my Eclipse IDE on my MacBook (macOS Catalina 10.15), by right clicking on the project then Export>Deployable plugins and Fragments>Install into host repository>Finish. The pathway for the host repository is `/Users/username/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/install/`. The attributes chosen in the Options category are shown in the photo below:

[image]

The plugin installs successfully and is able to run in my IDE upon button click.

When I repeat these steps in Windows 10, the plugin installs. I am able to click on a button to open my developed window, but when I click the "go" button which triggers my functions that rely on the external jars, nothing occurs. The button acts as though it is not connected to any function, despite the code being identical to what was used in Mac. **Does anyone know why Eclipse is unable to access the necessary jars in Windows?**

I have attached a screenshot of my build properties below. Note that the jars are held in a directory called "lib" which is at the same level as the /src directory in a eclipse plugin project.

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               icons/,\
               lib/commons-io-2.6.jar,\
               lib/daffodil-io_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
               lib/daffodil-japi_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
               lib/daffodil-lib_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
               lib/daffodil-runtime1_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
               lib/daffodil-runtime1-unparser_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
               lib/daffodil-udf_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
               lib/icu4j-62.1.jar,\
               lib/jackson-core-2.9.6.jar,\
               lib/jdom2-2.0.6.jar,\
               lib/jline-2.14.6.jar,\
               lib/scala-library-2.12.6.jar,\
               lib/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.1.jar,\
               lib/scala-xml_2.12-1.1.0.jar,\
               lib/stax2-api-4.1.jar,\
               lib/daffodil-core_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
               lib/woodstox-core-5.1.0.jar,\
               lib/xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar,\
               lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar,\
               lib/xml-resolver-1.2.jar
jars.compile.order = lib/scala-library-2.12.6.jar,\
                     lib/scala-xml_2.12-1.1.0.jar,\
                     lib/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.1.jar,\
                     lib/commons-io-2.6.jar,\
                     lib/daffodil-io_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
                     lib/daffodil-japi_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
                     lib/daffodil-lib_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
                     lib/daffodil-runtime1_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
                     lib/daffodil-runtime1-unparser_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
                     lib/daffodil-udf_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
                     lib/icu4j-62.1.jar,\
                     lib/jackson-core-2.9.6.jar,\
                     lib/jdom2-2.0.6.jar,\
                     lib/jline-2.14.6.jar,\
                     lib/stax2-api-4.1.jar,\
                     lib/daffodil-core_2.12-2.5.0.jar,\
                     lib/woodstox-core-5.1.0.jar,\
                     lib/xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar,\
                     lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar,\
                     lib/xml-resolver-1.2.jar,\
                     .
```

The plugin manifest is as shown below:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.companyName.plugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.0
Bundle-Vendor: VENDOR
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.core.resources
Automatic-Module-Name: com.companyName.plugin
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/commons-io-2.6.jar,
 lib/daffodil-io_2.12-2.5.0.jar,
 lib/daffodil-japi_2.12-2.5.0.jar,
 lib/daffodil-lib_2.12-2.5.0.jar,
 lib/daffodil-runtime1_2.12-2.5.0.jar,
 lib/daffodil-runtime1-unparser_2.12-2.5.0.jar,
 lib/daffodil-udf_2.12-2.5.0.jar,
 lib/icu4j-62.1.jar,
 lib/jackson-core-2.9.6.jar,
 lib/jdom2-2.0.6.jar,
 lib/jline-2.14.6.jar,
 lib/scala-library-2.12.6.jar,
 lib/scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.1.jar,
 lib/scala-xml_2.12-1.1.0.jar,
 lib/stax2-api-4.1.jar,
 lib/daffodil-core_2.12-2.5.0.jar,
 lib/woodstox-core-5.1.0.jar,
 lib/xercesImpl-2.12.0.jar,
 lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar,
 lib/xml-resolver-1.2.jar,
 .
```

I get the following errors in the C:\Users\userName\eclipse-workspace.metadata.log when trying to install the plugin in Windows. All of the methods below that are unable to be resolved are from the external jars that have been added to the project.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2020-07-21 16:42:07.814
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    DataProcessor cannot be resolved to a type
    The method createDataProcessor(File) from the type DaffFunct refers to the missing type DataProcessor
    InputSourceDataInputStream cannot be resolved to a type
    InputSourceDataInputStream cannot be resolved to a type
    InfosetOutputter cannot be resolved to a type
    InfosetOutputter cannot be resolved to a type
    XMLTextInfosetOutputter cannot be resolved to a type
    JsonInfosetOutputter cannot be resolved to a type
    ParseResult cannot be resolved to a type
    Diagnostic cannot be resolved to a type
    Diagnostic cannot be resolved to a type

    at com.nteligen.daffodil.handlers.DaffFunct.parse(DaffFunct.java:62)
    at com.nteligen.daffodil.handlers.ParseHandler$6.handleEvent(ParseHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3922)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3524)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
```

Comment: What is in the Bundle-Classpath in the MANIFEST.MF? Are there any messages in the log? Are all the jars actually present in the built plug-in?

Comment: I updated the question with the necessary information regarding the MANIFEST.MF and the log. When I open my jar using "jar tf jar_name" all of the added external jar files are present.

Comment: "Unresolved compilation problems" means your code does not even compile, you can't run code with compile errors.

Comment: My plugin works as intended when I test the plugin by having the plugin run in a runtime version of eclipse. I do not get any compilation errors there.  I only get compilation errors when I try to export and install the plugin in my normal eclipse workspace.

Comment: I am assuming that the jars need to be put in a different location or the build properties file needs to be altered to properly pull in the external jars, considering that the plugin performs as intended when clicking on the plugin.xml file for the project then clicking "run as Eclipse Application"

Comment: Instead of "Export > Deployable plugins and features" you should switch to the recommended method of building using [tag:maven] and [tag:tycho], see [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html). This is likely to give better messages about the export problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the issue appeared to be with the windows computer I was using. The plugin installed as intended with this code on another windows machine.